# How to implement Spring Jdbc to account for ALL relational databases?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I heard a lot about Spring, and decided to try it. I read  [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783987367) book about Spring, and still not sure if it will suit my purpose.

**What I need:** I have an application that currently hits `Oracle` database. I was thinking about modifying the source code to where I can point my application to **ANY** database. So, in the future, if I want it to hit `MYSQL`, I will only need to modify the `beans.xml` (and add the dependencies in the `dependencies` folder). But I'm not sure what is the best way to do this using Spring.

Is this what `Spring` made for? I looks like there will be a way more coding if I use Spring. I can do equally well creating my own   `configuration.xml` file, and parse it at the run time. Maybe I misunderstand Sring. I'm sure it's a great tool.

Can anybody provide a **REAL WORLD** example, of how Spring can be so awesome when dealing with an unknown database, i.e. "database gets revealed only at the run time" case. I read all those "Employee Class Textbook" examples, which make little sense  so far . They are so much far fetched

Comment: You should define the driver, how could it be possible to detect the driver of an unknown DB? You can write all possible db credentials to a configuration file and with some magic touch of try catch, you try them one by one and if you catch the correct one, voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is mainly a dependency injection framework. Spring MVC allows you to write applications in the Model-View-Controller architecture.

If you are looking into making your application agnostic to the underlying Database you should be looking into JPA which is the Java standard for dealing with persistence. There are a number of implementations of that standard, a popular one of which is Hibernate. It lets you write persistence code that can be executed against many different databases.

If you want to avoid dealing with the many configuration details you should consider using Spring-Boot which is a Spring project that simplifies the Spring configuration considerably, by using reasonable defaults and inferring some configuration from the libraries that you put in your class path.